# Minecraft Command NBT Array Add

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having (for example) a entity (Drop) with this NBT:

`{Item:{tag:{display:{Lore:["test1"]}},id:"minecraft:bread"}}`

I'm trying to add a new lore:

`/data merge entity @e[type=item,tag=myDrop] {Item:{tag:{display:{Lore:["test2"]}}}}`

But when I execute this and collect my drop there is ONLY test2 as lore but i need test1 and test2.
Please help!
Thanks.

EDIT: I don't know the content and/or the count of test1.

EDIT2: So simply a array.append() but how in minecraft?

Comment: Does it work if you specify `Item.tag.display.Lore[1]` as the path?

Comment: I have a lot of data and this is a part but I haven't tried path because i don't know how much test1 is there.

Comment: You mean you don't know how many lore lines there already are?

Comment: Yup. I don't know how many lines :|

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get the number of items in an NBT array. Also, I just noticed that `/data merge` doesn't have a path argument. I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: Oh. I must search another way to view my things :(

Comment: 1.14 has some nice new NBT editing commands, I think this should now be possible. I'll write an answer when I have time (and access to Minecraft), for now you might be able to figure it out using [this wiki page](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.14#Command_format_2) (scroll down to "Other").

Comment: @Fabian Röling Thanks, found another way to display my things, but added for Googlers as Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.14 introduces this feature using the "`append`" mode of `/data modify`:

```
/data modify entity @e[type=item,limit=1] Item.tag.display.Lore append value "{\"text\":\"second line\"}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
/data merge entity @e[type=item,limit=1] {Item:{tag:{display:{Lore:["test2","test1"]}}}}
```

You're still replacing the original `test1`, but you can just replace it with `test1`, or you could change it.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I have an lore I don't know and only want to add mine.(I'm making a custom enchantment in a datapack that works but i cant add the enchantment desc as a lore). See question edit.